# Javascript Manually Create Promise Rejection Object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I was wondering if it is possible to manually create a variable/object to simulate a Resolved or Rejected Promise.

I have the following code which is a working example of what I am trying to achieve but it just seems like a bit of a round about way of something that I'm hoping already exists.

If I have the following function

```
function fakeMulti() {
return new Promise(function(res, rej) {

   promises = [];

   // inst 01

   var flag = true;
   // this will pass and append resolved promise
   if(flag) {
      promises.push(*resolved*);
   } else {
      promises.push(*rejected*);
   }

   // inst 02

   var flag = false;
   // this will fail and append rejected promise
   if(flag) {
      promises.push(*resolved*);
   } else {
      promises.push(*rejected*);
   }

   // resolve

   Promise.all(promises).then(function(result) {
      res("FAKE MULTI PASS");
   }).catch(function(error) {
      rej("FAKE MULTI FAIL");
   });

});
}
```

The only way I've been able to create the Promise Resolve and Reject though is with a function that just returns a Promise

```
function forcePromise(type) {
return new Promise(function(res, rej) {

   if(type == "resolve") {
      res("RESOLVE");
   } else {
      rej("REJECT");
   }

});
}
```

which I can use and it works just fine

```
function fakeMulti() {
return new Promise(function(res, rej) {

   promises = [];

   // inst 01

   var flag = true;
   // this will pass and append resolved promise
   if(flag) {
      promises.push(forcePromise("resolve"));
   } else {
      promises.push(forcePromise("reject"));
   }

   // inst 02

   var flag = false;
   // this will fail and append rejected promise
   if(flag) {
      promises.push(forcePromise("resolve"));
   } else {
      promises.push(forcePromise("reject"));
   }

   // resolve

   Promise.all(promises).then(function(result) {
      res("FAKE MULTI PASS");
   }).catch(function(error) {
      rej("FAKE MULTI FAIL");
   });

});
}
```

But it seems a bit excessive and then I have to include this function for every instance I need this logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [`Promise.reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) and [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)?

Comment: I tried those but they didn't work

Comment: Oh, the promise constructor antipattern :(

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: How can I close this question so I can create one that better describes the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise.resolve, and Promise.reject should work,..

Here is a simple snippet, doing what it looks like your trying to do.

```js
function testMulti() {

  const m = [];
  m.push(Promise.resolve("this is ok"));
  m.push(Promise.reject("this should fail"));
  Promise.all(m).then(function (r) {
    console.log("success with: " + r);
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.log("Fail with: " + e);
  });

}

testMulti();
```

Comment: It seems that Promise.reject() does actually work but not in my code, it seems there is a different issue

Comment: How can I close this question so I can create one that better describes the issue

Comment: I assume you can just accept this one, and create a new one.

Comment: That's true, need more letters